# (Flutter) Align horizontal listview at bottom of screen (and related issues)

Tags: android, flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

My application requires a horizontal listview where items can be tapped on.

**Rough Layout description below**

```
Container
|_ Stack
    |_ (background content)
    |_ Column (overlay, align end vertically)
          |_ Expand (fill up space above)
          |_ ListView (horizontal)
          |_ SizedBox (padding)
```

**Problem**

When inserting this [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) (or uncommenting), Flutter throws a fit with the following error:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1852 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///C:/Users/CybeX/CozyUp/cozyup-mobile-flutter/lib/ui/components/ui_component_partner_selector.dart:76:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1852:16)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
#5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1777:7)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:14)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#400d9 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=395.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  axisDirection: right
...  crossAxisDirection: down
...  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#72596(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#601d0, ScrollDirection.idle)
RenderObject: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#400d9 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
```

I tried wrapping the `ListView` in an `Expanded` but this recentered it in the middle of the screen as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64065216/4628115). I tried adding an Expanded top as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63274006/4628115), but Flutter doesn't like this.

fwiw, tried [ShrinkWrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492017/how-to-vertical-align-listview-in-the-middle) too (wasn't really expecting much here - didn't help either)

**MVCE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> imgSrc = [
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/84.jpg",
          "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/82.jpg",
          "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/11.jpg",
          "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/61.jpg",
          "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
    ];

    List<Widget> _listviewItems() {
      return imgSrc
          .map((e) => Image.network(e))
          .map((e) => Image(
                image: e.image,
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                width: 64,
              ))
          .toList();
    }

    Widget w = Container(
        child: Stack(
      children: [
        // Center(
        //   child: cards.first,
        // ),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: _listviewItems(),
            )),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(width: double.infinity, child: w),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Image above is with `ListView` wrapped in `Expanded`, i.e.

```
   Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Container()
        ),
        ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: _listviewItems(),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 8,
        )
      ],
    )
```

**Question:**

How can I align a horizontal listview to the bottom of the screen allowing for horizontal scrolling (as shown in the image above)?

*fyi: I added `shrinkWrap: true` and wrapped the `Column` (inside the Stack) inside of an `Extended` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52023716/4628115)) resulting in an error that leads me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766847/4628115) which suggests the opposite - quite frustrating!*

Answer (score 0):

wrap your list view with container and give height to container like this

```
Container(
 height:50,
  ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: _listviewItems(),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I am avoiding static sizes - not a good idea

Comment: but there is no other option, i tried my self but it was the only option

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run 2 full code below 
Solution 1: You can use `bottomSheet` 
code snippet

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: ...
      body: ...
      bottomSheet: SizedBox(height: 64, child: listview()),
    );
```

Solution 2: Wrap `ListView` with `Align` and `SizedBox` 
code snippet

```
Expanded(
        child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 64,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: _listviewItems(),
        ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code of solution 1

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> imgSrc = [
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/84.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/82.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/11.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/61.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/5.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/6.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/7.jpg",
    ];

    Widget listview() {
      List<Widget> imgList = imgSrc
          .map((e) => Image.network(e))
          .map((e) => Image(
                image: e.image,
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                width: 64,
              ))
          .toList();

      return ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: imgList,
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('AppBar Demo')),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            //width: double.infinity,
            child: Text("other content")),
      ),
      bottomSheet: SizedBox(height: 64, child: listview()),
    );
  }
}
```

full code of solution 2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> imgSrc = [
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/84.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/82.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/11.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/61.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/2.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/3.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/5.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/6.jpg",
      "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/7.jpg",
    ];

    List<Widget> _listviewItems() {
      return imgSrc
          .map((e) => Image.network(e))
          .map((e) => Image(
                image: e.image,
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                width: 64,
              ))
          .toList();
    }

    Widget w = Container(
        child: Stack(
      children: [
        // Center(
        //   child: cards.first,
        // ),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 64,
                child: ListView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: _listviewItems(),
                ),
              ),
            )),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ));

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(width: double.infinity, child: w),
    );
  }
}
```